# ffmpeg: sws_scale returning wrong values in plane V during RGB to YUV420 conversion

Tags: c++, image-processing, ffmpeg

I am trying to use sws_scale to transform an image from RGB to YUV420P. The code I use in C++ is the following:

```
SwsContext *swscontext = sws_getContext(current_width,
                                        current_height,
                                        PIX_FMT_RGB24,
                                        current_width,
                                        current_height,
                                        PIX_FMT_YUV420P,
                                        SWS_FAST_BILINEAR,
                                        NULL,
                                        NULL,
                                        NULL);
const int srcstride[3] = {current_width * 3, 0, 0};
BYTE *data_pos[3] = {data, NULL, NULL};
BYTE *dest[3] = {yuv,
                yuv + current_width * current_height,
                yuv + (current_width * current_height) 
                    + ((current_width * current_height) / 2)};
const int dststride[3] = {current_width, current_width / 2, current_width / 2};
sws_scale(swscontext, data_pos, srcstride, 0, current_height,
          dest, dststride);
```

The Y and U planes are encoded properly but the V plane is completely written with the value `0x80` I wonder if I am doing anything wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I still have no idea of why it works, but this solved the problem:

```
BYTE *dest[3] = {yuv,
                 yuv + current_width * current_height,
                 yuv + (current_width * current_height) 
                     + ((current_width >> 1) * (current_height >> 1))};
```

Semantically they are the same, so I will leave this question open in case someone come up with an explanation.

Comment: Actually, they're not the same. Look at `(current_width * current_height) / 2` and `(current_width >> 1) * (current_height >> 1)`. The key: `(current_width >> 1) * (current_height >> 1)` == `(current_width / 2) * (current_height / 2)` == `(current_width * current_height) / 4`.